# multiple clicks on protractor do not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am writing a protractor code that preforms some clicks on the same page.
for some reason it only preforms one click and then finishing the test successfully.
FYI
the clicks aren't redirecting the browser somewhere else

```
function hitl (i)
{
  nodes.get(i).click().then(
    function(){
  //  browser.driver.sleep(1000);
    i++
     if(i<nodes.length)
        hitl(i);
}  );

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can make it simpler using [`each()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each):

```
nodes.each(function (node) {
    node.click();
});
```

Comment: each clicks brings me something from the server. i want to wait for the ajax response and then to make the next click what to do?

Comment: @ShaySandler are there any indications on the page - may be some new elements appear, or there is a spinner/loading indicator?.. Thanks.

Comment: yes, a table appears or a error log in the lower pane

Comment: @ShaySandler in this case, you should use that fact to make a wait. The idea is to use [`browser.wait()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) with some specific [expected condition](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions). For instance, `browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element(by.id("myid")), 5000);`..difficult to say more in this case - don't know much about your page. And anyway, this would be a part of a separate question. Hope that helps.